# removing previous UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have three view controller with three different XIB, let's say ViewControllerA, ViewControllerB and ViewControllerC and every view controller has UIView variable named view in it's property. so it would be something like this :

```
@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *view;
```

first, scene ViewControllerA loaded, then after i touched a button scene of ViewControllerB appears. but i deliberately not removing UIView of ViewControllerA from super view.
Then after i touched a button the scene navigate to ViewControllerC. here, before navigate to ViewControllerC i want remove UIView both of ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB from super view

removing UIView of ViewControllerB is not a problem, i can do something like this in ViewControllerB method :

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

but how can i remove UIView of ViewControllerA?

thanks

Comment: ae you adding both viewcontroller's view  as subviews ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MidhunMP each view controller has UIView respectively and not related with another view controllers

Comment: @user1606616: then what are you trying to remove ?

Comment: @MidhunMP and Deepak i want remove UIView of ViewControllerA when i accessing ViewControllerC, but to access ViewControllerC, i must access ViewControllerB. and in ViewControllerB i still want UIView from ViewControllerA as a "dummy view". sorry if it's confusing

Comment: why you need to remove the view? just create a new view and add it to the parent view, replace it!

Comment: what are you trying to do ? You need to reuse the view controller A?

Comment: @Deepak well, maybe it's little confusing. now let's say view controller as A, B and C. A is main menu, B is submenu and C is totally new scene that accessed can only accessed from B.
actually when i access B's UIView, i want the A's UIView as background, so it's still visible.
when i access C through B, i want the A and B's UIView removed. but i just can remove B UIView. i'm having trouble removing A UIView.

well, it's like that

Comment: can you please mention how you added view c? you added it as subview of B?

Comment: nope, it's 3 view controller with 3 XIB files. each view controller not related by using subview, because actually theres a lot of content and function in each XIB and view controller

Comment: ok, then all that you can do is navigate from one xib to other, you dont need to remove its view. just replace with new view

Answer (score 0):

If you want totally independent of each other view controllers, you could switch them in appDelegate.window.rootViewController. Only create variable appDelegate that points to UIApplication.

And handle the animations by yourself.

Example:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UIViewController *controller1 = [ViewControllerA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerA" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller2 = [ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerB" bundle:nil];

appDelegate.window.rootViewController = controller1;
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = controller2;
```

Comment: uhh, actually i just want remove UIView of ViewControllerA when i access ViewControllerC.
or by create UIViewController universal through AppDelegate i can directly access every UIViewController that initialized in AppDelegate?

Comment: You can access all public properties of all public instances within appDelegate.
E.g. "appDelegate.controller1.view" will return you the main view of controller1. Also [appDelegate.controller1.newCreatedButton removeFromSuperView] will remove the button.

Comment: hmm, sounds long way that i need rebuild my current app. i need to remove UIView of ViewControllerA. but i'll give a hit, it's sound reasonable to make it public instances so i can access globally